# WCF writing Nested Json Webservice

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, web-services, wcf

I have to write a WCF webservice in dot net in `nested Json`  structured below. I know how to write simple json but not sure to make it nested for `results

```
{
    "version": 2,


        "results": [{
        "company": "ABC Company Inc.",
        "city": "Sacramento",
        "state": "CA"
    }

    ]
}
```

What I am doing is :

**file1.cs**

```
namespace Test
{
    public class file1
    {
        public class child
        {
            [DataMember]
            public string version { get; set; }
        }

        public class parent
        {
            [DataMember]
            public string company { get; set; }

            [DataMember]
            public string city { get; set; }

        }
    }
}
```

In **file2.svc.cs**

```
public List<file1> method()
     {


         List<file1.child> result = new List<file1.child>();
         List<file1.parent> result1 = new List<file1.parent>();
         List<file1> final = new List<file1>();
         foreach (DataRow catt1 in dtcategory.Rows)
         {



             result.Add(new file1.child()
             {
                 version= catt1["version"].ToString(),

                });


             result1.Add(new file1.parent() {

                 company= catt1["company"].ToString(),
                 city= catt1["city"].ToString(),


             });
             final.Add(new file1()
             {


             });
              }


         return Add;

     }
```

Please let me where I am going wrong

Answer (score 0):

Class Structure:

```
public class class1
{

[DataMember]
public string version {get;set;}

[DataMember]
public List<class2> results {get;set;}

}

public class class2
{

[DataMember]
public string company {get;set;}


[DataMember]
public string city{get;set;}

[DataMember]
public string state {get;set;}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is sort of unclear.  However, if you are asking "how can I design my classes `file1.child` and `file1.parent` so that, when serialized by [`DataContractJsonSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [`Json.NET`](http://james.newtonking.com/json), they produce the JSON shown", then you can do:

```
    public class file1
    {
        [DataContract]
        public class child
        {
            [DataMember(Name="version")]
            public string Version { get; set; }

            [DataMember(Name="results")]
            public List<parent> Results { get; set; }
        }

        [DataContract]
        public class parent
        {
            [DataMember(Name="company")]
            public string Company { get; set; }

            [DataMember(Name="city")]
            public string City { get; set; }

            [DataMember(Name="state")]
            public string State { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

Note that, given your class names, `parent` is contained inside `child`, which is counterintuitive.  You might want to change those names.